# What to do with dry skin?

Tags: personal-care

I have very dry skin. Specially in winter season I faced this problem alot. I used lotion daily but it is not effected too much. What home remedy should we do for this.

Answer (score 2):

If your skin is very dry apply a body/facial oil on top of a moisturizer. If your skin is too dry the oil won't absorb.

Apply the moisturizer/lotion/serum and allow it to soak in for ~2 mins, then add 4-10 drops of oil and massage into skin.